# Understanding `runEval` - Not WHNF?

Tags: haskell

Given:

```
Prelude> import Control.Parallel.Strategies 
Prelude> import Control.Parallel
Prelude> let fact n = if (n <= 0) then 1 else n * fact (n-1) :: Integer
Prelude> let xs = map (runEval . (\x -> return x :: Eval Integer) . fact) [1..100]
Prelude> let ys = map fact [1..100]
Prelude> :sprint xs
xs = _
Prelude> :sprint ys
ys = _
```

As I understand, `xs` is in Weak Head Normal Form. Why is that? Didn't the `runEval` have any affect on bringing the value/computation to Normal Form?

Comment: Probably because you didn't specify where `runEval` or `Eval` are coming from.

Comment: thanks, David. I usually include `import`'s - my mistake.

Comment: `:sprint xs` prints `_` because you haven't forced any evaluation of `xs` - it has nothing to do with `runEval`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that `let` just binds a name with an expression but it doesn't trigger any evaluation of the expression.

To understand better, let me use a more simple example

```
Main> let x = error "foobar!" in 1
1
```

As you can see, the `error "foobar!"`, that should throw exception, is just ignored. The reason is that `x` is not used and thus Haskell doesn't evaluate it. You need something to trigger the evaluation of `x`

```
Main> let x = error "foobar!" in x `seq` 1
*** Exception: foobar!
```

Going back to your example, note that `Eval x` specifies how to evaluate a x, not when it will be evaluated in your program.

Have a look at this wiki article on [Lazyness](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Laziness) for more.